# Tool to create aliases for commands

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've just started learning Python 3 about a month ago. I created a tool, which allows the user to quickly access some long commands.

For instance, at my day job I have to type things like these a couple times a day:

- `ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa user@server`
- `docker exec -i mysql_container_name mysql -u example -pexample example < example.sql`

This really annoys me, so I created a tool which would allow me to run `a ssh` or `a import` and save me a lot of time.

But since I'm new to Python, I seek tips on how to improve my code.

```
import re
import os
import sys
import yaml
from a.Helper import Helper


class A(object):
    _argument_dict = {}
    _argument_list = []
    _settings = {}

    # Run a command
    def run(self, command, arguments):    
        self._load_config_files()
        self._validate_config_version()
        self._separate_arguments(arguments)
        self._initiate_run(command)

    # Reparse and return settigns
    def get_settings(self):
        self._load_config_files()
        self._validate_config_version()

        return self._settings

    # Load all the config files into one dictionary
    def _load_config_files(self):
        default_settings = {}
        local_settings = {}

        try:
            default_settings = self._load_config_file(os.path.dirname(__file__))
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("Can't locate native alias.yml file, the app is corrupt. Please reinstall.")
            sys.exit()

        cwd_list = os.getcwd().split('/')

        while not cwd_list == ['']:
            path = "/".join(cwd_list)

            try:
                local_settings = self._merge_settings(local_settings, self._load_config_file(path))
            except FileNotFoundError:
                pass

            cwd_list = cwd_list[:-1]

        self._settings = self._merge_settings(default_settings, local_settings)

    # Load a specific config file from specific location
    def _load_config_file(self, path):
        with open(path + "/alias.yml", "r") as stream:
            try:
                config = yaml.load(stream)
                config = self._reparse_config_with_constants(config, path)

                return config
            except yaml.YAMLError as ex:
                print(ex)
                sys.exit()

    # Go over the configs and substitute the so-far only one constant
    def _reparse_config_with_constants(self, config, path):
        try:
            for commands in config['commands']:
                if isinstance(config['commands'][commands], str):
                    config['commands'][commands] = config['commands'][commands].replace("{{cwd}}", path)
                elif isinstance(config['commands'][commands], list):
                    for id, command in enumerate(config['commands'][commands]):
                        config['commands'][commands][id] = command.replace("{{cwd}}", path)
        except KeyError:
            pass

        return config

    # Merge the settings so that all of them are available.
    def _merge_settings(self, source, destination):
        for key, value in source.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                node = destination.setdefault(key, {})
                self._merge_settings(value, node)
            else:
                destination[key] = value

        return destination

    # Parse arguments to dictionary and list. Dictionary is for named variables, list is for anonymous ones.
    def _separate_arguments(self, arguments):
        prepared_dict = []

        for argument in arguments:
            match = re.match(r"--([\w]+)=([\w\s]+)", argument)

            if match:
                prepared_dict.append((match.group(1), match.group(2)))
            else:
                self._argument_list.append(argument)

        self._argument_dict = dict(prepared_dict)

    # Die if yaml file version is not supported
    def _validate_config_version(self):
        if self._settings['version'] > self._settings['supported_version']:
            print("alias.yml version is not supported")
            sys.exit()

    # Prepare and run specific command
    def _initiate_run(self, command_name):
        try:
            command_list = self._settings['commands'][command_name]
            argument_list_cycler = iter(self._argument_list)

            # Replace a variable name with either a value from argument dictionary or from argument list
            def replace_variable_match(match):
                try:
                    return self._argument_dict[match.group(1)]
                except KeyError:
                    return next(argument_list_cycler)

            # Replace and
            def run_command(command):
                command = re.sub(r"%%([a-z_]+)%%", replace_variable_match, command)
                os.system(command)

            if isinstance(command_list, str):
                run_command(command_list)
            elif isinstance(command_list, list):
                for command in command_list:
                    run_command(command)
            else:
                Helper(self._settings)
        except StopIteration:
            print("FATAL: You did not specify the variable value for your command.")
            sys.exit()
        except IndexError:
            Helper(self._settings)
            sys.exit()
        except KeyError:
            Helper(self._settings)
            sys.exit()
```

**Quick config explanation**

The tool allows the user to create a `alias.yml` file in some directory and all the commands the user specifies there will be available in any subdirectory. The config file (`alias.yml`) might contain either one command as string or a list of commands and has to look like this:

```
version: 1.0 # For future version, which could introduce breaking changes

commands:
  echo: echo Hello World
  ssh:
    - scp file user@remote:/home/user/file
    - ssh user@remote
```

I introduced a possibility to use variables in `%%variable%%` format in the specified commands and the user is required to specify them on run. For instance:

```
commands:
  echo: echo %%echo%%
```

This will require the user to type `a echo Hello` to produce the output of `Hello`.

And there is also a specific constant `{{cwd}}` (as "config working directory) to allow the user to run path-specific commands. For example, we use `php-cs-fixer` inside a specific directory and running the command invoking `php-cs-fixer` will fail in any subdirectory. Thus the config has to be written as this:

```
command:
  cs: {{cwd}}/cs/php-cs-fixer --dry-run
```

Since this config is located in `/home/user/php/project`, `{{cwd}}` gets substituted with that path and then `/home/user/php/project/cs/php-cs-fixer` is being executed. This allows me to run `a cs` even from `/home/user/php/project/code/src/Entity/etc/etc` - you got the point.

**Entrypoint**

Whenever `a` is invoked with arguments, `__main` runs `run` from the above class. I wanted to be more OOP-like, so the arguments passed to `run` are from `sys.argv`: `a.run(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2::])`.

**Conclusion**

I really wonder how to improve the `A` class posted above, both from the architectural and structural point of view. But if you'd like to give more tips on improving the code in overall, the repository is [here](https://github.com/flexbox-it/any-alias).

Comment: You do know that all POSIX compliant shells have the `alias` command, which allows giving a name to a command? Also, `ssh` has the `~/.ssh/config` file where you can configure hosts (including ports and users).

Comment: I do. But I think you missed a bigger picture here.

Comment: If I thought this could replace your whole code, I would have made it an answer. This was just to check if you knew the obvious alternatives for some of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general I see some great code for someone so new to the language.  There is quite a bit code here, and I have but time for a few style notes.

#### Python has lots of great ways to iterate

Here is a loop  that really caught my eye.  The iterating variable is being continually used to reaccess the iterated data, and thus ends up with a lot of boilerplate.  This generally harms readability.

```
for commands in config['commands']:
    if isinstance(config['commands'][commands], str):
        config['commands'][commands] = config['commands'][commands].replace("{{cwd}}", path)
    elif isinstance(config['commands'][commands], list):
        for id, command in enumerate(config['commands'][commands]):
            config['commands'][commands][id] = command.replace("{{cwd}}", path)
```

Continually reaccessing `config['commands']`, when instead something like:

```
for name, command in config['commands'].items():
```

will allow access to the value at `config['commands']`.  This cleans up the code when that value is accessed:

```
for name, command in config['commands'].items():
    if isinstance(command, str):
        config['commands'][name] = command.replace("{{cwd}}", path)
    elif isinstance(command, list):
        command[:] = [c.replace("{{cwd}}", path) for c in command]
```

But in the case of mutable values, can clean up the assignment of those values as well:

```
command[:] = [c.replace("{{cwd}}", path) for c in command]
```

<sub>Note:  I did not actually test this code, so it may hide some stupid typos.</sub>

#### No point in constructing an object that can not be used

In this construct (pared down):

```
default_settings = {}
try:
    default_settings = self._load_config_file(os.path.dirname(__file__))
except FileNotFoundError:
    sys.exit()
```

This line:

```
default_settings = {}
```

is unneeded, since it will always set in the case in which the program does not exit.

#### Intermediate Assignments:

Something like this:

```
node = destination.setdefault(key, {})
self._merge_settings(value, node)
```

I generally prefer something like:

```
self._merge_settings(value, destination.setdefault(key, {}))
```

If the name `node` provides some important documentation function, or the expression is more complex, then an intermediate assignment can make some sense, but if not...